# /var/run/utmp does not record users who log in through GUI and ‘w’ command can not show users that have logged in through GUI

Tags: login, users, 18.10

I’ve deleted some files in /var directory by accident and I found the problem that I describe in the title.
How can I solve that problem?
Is there any way to recover /var/run/utmp?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what files you deleted? perhaps by looking back through your shell history

Comment: Sorry I can't. I just typed the command "  rm -rf /var" unconsciously and I cut if off when I found what I had done.

Comment: I also wish to know how to implement the command "w".